How to send data to children processes from parent process using queue?
I am trying to process a queue of files by spawning multiple processes. I want to spawn two children processes in order to traverse a queue of files. As soon as the process of one file ends, the process should pick the next file in the queue and this should go on till the queue is empty.
I know that the memory is copied from parent process for a spawned child process and I am not able to maintain a single queue in order to keep a track of files processed.
Here's my implementation:
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector < pid_t > process;
    pid_t pid = 0;
    queue<string> files;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        string str = "str" + std::to_string(i);
        files.push(str);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << "Prefork child process! " << i<< endl;
        pid = fork ();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            string curr = files.front();
            files.pop();
            cout << "Hello from the child process! " << i << endl;
            cout << "I got : " << curr << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            process.push_back(pid);
            cout << "Parent for child "<< i << " with pid: " << pid  << endl;
        }

    }
    int status;
    while ((pid=waitpid(-1, &status, 0))!=-1) {
        cout << "Process terminated: " << pid << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

In this, I got str1 as input to both processes, but ideally child 1 should get str1, child2 should get str2 and when the process of str1 is completed by child 1, it should pick str3 and so on till the queue is empty.

std::vector cannot be shared across processes without synchronization. You need a proper queue.

Hi, @Quimby, I don't want to share the vector, I want to share queue<string> files;.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/interprocess.html has some support for process interactions (shared memory, special pointers), but normally you'd just use pipes. The real question is, why processes instead of threads? Threads will naturally share their resources, so communication is trivial.

@TejasSharma sorry my mistake. For std:queue the answer is still the same, you cannot share it across process boundaries just like this.

@ChristianStieber I am using APIs which are not thread safe and I don't have the authority over that code.

In that case, and if whatever APIs you are using are too time-consuming for a mutex, and you definitely don't want to just run things in sequence, your only option besides boost::interprocess (which I have no experience with) or similar libraries, or native shared memory, would be to design a protocol for the processes to communicate over pipes. Like "send name, wait for result, send next name" on the main process to distribute tasks and collect the results.
